# How to block readback via JTAG using BSCAN_SPARTAN3A macro?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

How to block readback via JTAG using BSCAN_SPARTAN3A macro? I want to block the JTAG port in my board and it will available for PROGRAM/ERASE functions only, and deny for READBACK.

Answer (score 3):

In Xilinx ISE select the "Design" panel tab, then right click "Generate Programming File", and select "Process Properties".  To the left you can select "Readback Options", and then the right pane will shown a "Security" property for control of readback, as shown below.

[image]